# Add taxonomy terms to files

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, files

Is it possible to add a taxonomy term to a file that it is uploaded to the site? If not I imagine that I would need to create a content type to encapsulate the file and tag that.

Comment: in Drupal 7, media module make file fieldable. but in drupal 6 you need create a content-type...

Answer (score 1):

Your file would need to be fieldable. i.e. - using something like the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module.

More complete media solutions exists also, like [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media), [Scald](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald), or [Asset](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset) exist which would provide this and more.